# My system() command gives some warning which needs to be ignored. How can i hide the warning?

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system

My code : ***system("systemctl reload httpd");***

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to modify your `system` call to something like this:

```
system("systemctl reload httpd 2> /dev/null");
```

---

Another solution if you don't want to modify your `system` call is to temporarily "disable" `stderr` (and `stdout`, if necessary):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int fd = dup(STDERR_FILENO); // or STDOUT_FILENO

freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
system("systemctl reload httpd");
fflush(stderr);

// restore stderr to its original state
close(STDERR_FILENO);
dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO);
```